# How to get JavaFX Inherited CSS Properties

Tags: css, javafx, fonts, properties, root

I am looking for the command to get all properties of a Node, even those inherited from the default CSS stylesheet. The most close method I found is the "***impl_getStyleMap()***" but it is a deprecated method.

More precisely I have the following:

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-font-size: 18;
}
```

And I want through java code to get the -fx-font-size that is now inherited by all scene components.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know how to do this.  SceneBuilder has a CSS inspector and its source is open source. *Perhaps* there are some utilities or algorithms in the [SceneBuilder source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/src/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/css) that may assist you.  You might also wish to ask the [Oracle JavaFX forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java_desktop/javafx_2.0_and_later), in case a developer than can assist you.